# How to create MySQL query that converts rows to columns?

Tags: mysql, time-series, case, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I'm creating an employee tracking app.

I have a MySQL table which is as follows:

| ID | PersonID | TypeID | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | IN | 2022-09-01T13:21:12 |
| 2 | 001 | OUT | 2022-09-01T13:25:12 |
| 3 | 001 | IN | 2022-09-01T14:21:12 |
| 4 | 001 | OUT | 2022-09-01T14:25:12 |
| 5 | 002 | IN | 2022-09-03T13:21:12 |
| 6 | 002 | OUT | 2022-09-03T13:25:12 |
| 7 | 002 | IN | 2022-09-03T14:21:12 |
| 8 | 002 | IN | 2022-09-03T14:25:12 |
| 9 | 002 | OUT | 2022-09-03T14:25:12 |
| 10 | 002 | OUT | 2022-09-03T16:25:12 |
| 11 | 002 | OUT | 2022-09-03T17:25:12 |
| 12 | 002 | IN | 2022-09-04T16:25:12 |
| 13 | 002 | IN | 2022-09-05T17:25:12 |

I would like to create a view that returns records first sorted by PersonID and then by the ID but transforms the rows into columns.

Something like this:

| PersonID | InID | In_DateTime | OutID | Out_DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 2022-09-01T13:21:12 | 2 | 2022-09-01T13:25:12 |
| 001 | 3 | 2022-09-01T14:21:12 | 4 | 2022-09-01T14:25:12 |
| 002 | 5 | 2022-09-03T13:21:12 | 6 | 2022-09-03T13:25:12 |
| 002 | 7 | 2022-09-03T14:21:12 | null | null |
| 002 | 8 | 2022-09-03T14:25:12 | 9 | 2022-09-03T14:25:12 |
| 002 | null | null | 10 | 2022-09-03T16:25:12 |
| 002 | null | null | 11 | 2022-09-03T17:25:12 |
| 002 | 12 | 2022-09-04T16:25:12 | null | null |
| 002 | 13 | 2022-09-05T17:25:12 | null | null |

Does anyone have an idea how to do this in MySQL?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You are looking for pivoting. Please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns

Comment: On the first glance it seems that you need MySQL emulation of `FULL OUTER SELF JOIN`.

Comment: I disagree with the above 2 comments.  This looks like a gaps and islands problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions `LEAD()` or `LAG()` to get for each row its pair row, depending on its `TypeID` and do a left join of the results to the table:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
     CASE 
       WHEN TypeID = 'IN' AND LEAD(TypeID) OVER w = 'OUT' THEN LEAD(ID) OVER w
       WHEN TypeID = 'OUT' AND LAG(TypeID) OVER w = 'IN' THEN LAG(ID) OVER w
     END other_ID  
  FROM tablename
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY DateTime)
)
SELECT DISTINCT c.PersonID,
       CASE WHEN c.TypeID = 'IN' THEN c.ID ELSE t.ID END InID,
       CASE WHEN c.TypeID = 'IN' THEN c.DateTime ELSE t.DateTime END In_DateTime,
       CASE WHEN c.TypeID = 'IN' THEN t.ID ELSE c.ID END OutID,
       CASE WHEN c.TypeID = 'IN' THEN t.DateTime ELSE c.DateTime END Out_DateTime
FROM cte c LEFT JOIN tablename t
ON t.ID = c.other_ID
ORDER BY c.PersonID, COALESCE(In_DateTime, Out_DateTime);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rZMpzPPZybJc7MbgWXHN86/0).